# How do I retrieve a menu using its link?

Tags: 8, navigation

Let say I have a menu item with these attributes

```
'title' => 'Menu Title',
'link' => ['uri' => 'internal:/taxonomy/term/1217'],
'menu_name' => 'my-menu',
'expanded' => TRUE,
```

I can find all the menus by their title, e.g.,

```
 $menu_links = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('menu_link_content')
                ->loadByProperties(['title' => 'Menu Title']);

if ($menu_link = reset($menu_links)) {
// Get the pid of the first menu
    $menu_pid = $menu_link->getPluginId();
}
```

Then I tried to retrieve menu by the link property, and I couldn't.
I tried:

```
 $menu_links = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('menu_link_content')
                ->loadByProperties(['link' => array('uri' => 'internal:/taxonomy/term/1217')]);

 $menu_links = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('menu_link_content')
                ->loadByProperties(['link' => ['uri' => 'internal:/taxonomy/term/1217']]);

 $menu_links = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('menu_link_content')
                ->loadByProperties(['uri' => 'internal:/taxonomy/term/1217']);
```

None of them worked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the property `link.uri`:

```
$menu_links = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('menu_link_content')
  ->loadByProperties(['link.uri' => 'internal:' . $path]);
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
$link = 'entity:node/' . $node->id();
$menulinks = \Drupal::service('entity.manager')->getStorage('menu_link_content')
    ->loadByProperties(['link.uri' => $link]);
```

So I think you should try `'entity:'` instead of `'internal:'`